# Selecting a record where all associations are present

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, activerecord, associations, where-clause

I have a user that has_many levels. Let's say I have levels 1, 2, 3, and 4. 
How do I search for users that have associations with levels 2 AND 3 but not 4?
I haven't gotten for myself. I wanted to focus first on the part before 'but' however the line I came up with:

```
User.includes(:levels).where(levels: {id: [2, 3]})
```

returns also users that has only association with level 2, and not only the users with both levels 2 and 3.

Comment: That seems really odd. I would recommend appending `.to_sql` to the end of the line, or trying it in the console and inspecting the SQL output. This appears to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Below will work if the order of ids obtained is as [2,3] only. For [3, 2] it will show no records. If the object are in sequence then it should work.

```
User.includes(:levels).map(&:levels).select { |l| l if l.ids == [2, 3] }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.includes(:levels).where(levels: {id: 2}).where(levels: {id: 3})
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.